# How to change a template file the right way?

Tags: template, extensions, frontend, layout-update

I want to add an additional CSS class to my template which is located here:

```
app/design/frontend/default/ves_fashion/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/login.phtml
```

I am asking myself now what is the **correct way** in Magento?

Should I change the **login.phtml** in that directory above or should I create a duplicate of that **login.phtml** and add it to my own extension at:    `app/code/local/MyExtension/ShippingMethodExtension/Block/Checkout/Onepage/login.phtml`

How can I then tell Magento that it should use the **login.phtml** of my extension and not the one from the **persistent** folder?

Would be great if someone can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a layout file for doing this:

```
<?xml version="1.0">
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><file>css/your.css</file></action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Then in your config.xml you will have to reference this layout file:

```
<layout>
    <updates>
        <bla_login>
            <file>bla/login.xml</file>
        </bla_login>
    </updates>
</layout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer - so no need for an extension? Where do I find the right element which I must put in "<bla_login"> ?

Comment: Yes, you should create an extension for this. then replace bla with your a name that suites you. I suggest that you read how to create an extension to have a better understanding of the config.xml and then for more specific  check this nice tutorials to get a better idea of magento layouts: http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/demystifying-magentos-layout-xml-part-1/ and http://www.classyllama.com/blog/the-better-way-to-modify-magento-layouts

Comment: Hey thanks. I tried it - I understand the concept a bit better, but still there are some questions:
I have a config.xml of my module which has some content starting with <content> because it is already rewriting a php file which has been added with an extension. after </content> is closed i added <frontend><layout>... from my themes checkout.xml I copied the <reference> tag and its contents which defines the login.phtml to my config.xml and changed the path of the template. But nothing changes. Do you have another hint for me?

Comment: Every time you change your config.xml flush the cache to see the changes